# Truffle error when deploy a contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Does anybody know how to solve this? I've try to compile and deploy my contract to get the address, why obtained this error

Error:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'towater'
   -------------------------
Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"towater" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 2!.

    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.0.24 (core: 5.0.24)
Node v10.16.0
```

[image: that's image of error that I obtained]

`1_initial_migrations.js` file:

```
var towater = artifacts.require("towater");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(towater);
};
```

[image]

Comment: Check in the migration file if you are specifying the constructor arguments of `towater`.

Comment: How I do this? Check my migration file

Comment: The constructor of towater have 2 params, string[] and bytes16[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the error you need to pass the arguments of the constructor in your `migration` file.

Based on your two params:

```
// Untested
// Deploy a single contract with constructor arguments
deployer.deploy(towater, ["string_1", "string_2"], ["0x15458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0x15458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa734c"] );
```

Check the [Truffle docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-deploy-contract-args-options-).

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhh, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When working with Truffle v5.0.39, the above-mentioned syntax is not valid.
If the contract's constructor has arguments, the deploy function has to provide the arguments like this:

```
deployer.deploy( myContract, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

So, for example, if your constructor takes two addresses:

```
deployer.deploy(towater, "0x15458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c", "0x15458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa734c");
```